# Redux Action does not recognize the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been building a React and Redux app. I created a simple container and an action creator which carries an action with a simple console.log() one of the users I have written down in the state (reducer).

The problem is, when I click on the rendered state, it says 'user' is not defined. Why? What can I do to let the function recognize the state?

Container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {selectUser} from '../actions/index';


class UserList extends Component {

renderUser() {  
    return <div onClick={this.props.selectUser(user)}>
             {this.props.users[0].giovanni}
              </div>
           }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderUser()}</div>
        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }

}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectUser: selectUser}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);
```

Action

```
export const selectUser = (user) => {
    console.log('yo how are you?', user.users[0]);
    return {
        type: 'USER_SELECTED',
        payload: user
    }    
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function () {
    return [
        {
        giovanni: 'operaio',
        marco: 'vigile',
        luca: 'esattore',
        }
    ]
}
```

Index Reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import reducerMain from './reducer_main';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    users: reducerMain
});

export default allReducers;
```

Comment: what do you expect `user` variable to be?

Comment: it's a dummy parameter used to let the 'giovanni:  operaio' render

Comment: the strange thing is that operaio is rendered, but when I call the action 'user' it's not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks incorrect for a number of reasons

```
renderUser() {  
  return (
     <div onClick={this.props.selectUser(user)}>
       {this.props.users[0].giovanni}
     </div>
  );
}
```

`onClick` receives a function. In all likelihood, you meant the following

```
    <div onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(user)}>
```

And not the call to `this.props.selectUser` by itself.

What is `user`? It is not defined. I guess you meant

```
  renderUser() {  
    return (
       <div onClick={() => this.props.selectUser(this.props.users[0])}>
         {this.props.users[0].giovanni}
       </div>
    );
  }
```

The action must look like this, since the user object is already passed

```
export const selectUser = (user) => {
    console.log('yo how are you?', user);
    return {
        type: 'USER_SELECTED',
        payload: user
    }    
}
```

Comment: you are totally right for the first part of the answer, my bad. But it still does not render. Now it says users[0] is not defined

Comment: it's still not defined. Maybe is there anything to change in the action creator?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is not defined? Either `this.props.users[0]` is defined in both the places, or nowhere.

Comment: when you click on 'operaio', the console.log does not pop up throwing this error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at selectUser

Comment: Updated my answer again

Answer (score 0):

You event handler will trigger asynchronous update of the state, so you will most likely not have the value on the same rendering of the component, you can use a default value if it is not set for example: `this.props.users[0].giovanni || ''}` in case there is not value or a conditional rendering.

Comment: do you mean to pass this.props.users[0].giovanni || '' as a parameter?

Comment: I mean to check first if 'giovanni' exists and then render it (it will not be updated right after you call your handler, so it will fail in render if you don't chech it). You can do `{this.props.users.lenght > 0 ? render giovanni here : use default value` or `{this.props.users.length > 0 && render jiovanni component here}`.